# Is it possible to use material DayNight theme on Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I think that this is the bug in Xamarin.Android, but possibly there is some way to do this.

I wanted to use material daynight theme and what I did is replacing this line in styles.xml (that worked):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
```

with this one:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
```

which produces this error:

```
resource android:style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight not found.
```

Obviously as the first theme worked I have already installed `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` package and I've tried to clean the project even to run the project on a different PC.

If someone knows some solution for this it would be very helpful, if not I guess it is a bug and I'll file the bug then.

Comment: Do you use AndroidX in your project? If so, you can refer to this link :https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/12 , this issue was reprotected.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT thanks, I commented there, four months ago they've said it is 'just to be released' and still nothing.

Comment: You are welcome, you also could open a free ticket for support https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6  If the github link no update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. Material Design Library is still new thus continuously getting updated and as of right now the latest stable version of the material design library for Xamarin Android is [1.0.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material/1.0.0.1) which does not include material DayNight theme.

However, if you want to support DayNight theme you can use one of the pre-release versions of the library. Run below command on the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and it will install the Version [1.1.0.1-rc3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material/1.1.0.1-rc3) which includes material DayNight theme.

```
PM> Install-Package Xamarin.Google.Android.Material -Version 1.1.0.1-rc3
```

**Edit:**

I've just noticed that you are declaring parent as `android:Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`. This has to be changed to `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`.

Also if you want to customize colors and styles for dark theme, you need to create a folder called `values-night` inside the `Resources` folder and have a separate `styles.xml` file for dark theme with different colors and styles.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
<item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
<item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>
<item name="colorError">@color/colorError</item>
<item name="colorOnError">@color/colorOnError</item>
<item name="colorSurface">@color/colorSurface</item>
<item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorOnSurface</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
<item name="colorOnBackground">@color/colorOnBackground</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks but that is full of incorrect info. Most notably there is no DayNight theme even in the pre-release versions, I have tried it already.

Comment: I cannot say for sure what your specific issue might be with the given info above but my answer is correct and I have been using Material Design DayNight theme for over 3 months now with the pre release version 1.1.0-rc3. And just now I tried it with the latest version and still work perfectly. Are you sure you have values-night folder in the resources and have separate styles.xml file there for dark theme?

Comment: when I add DayNight theme, the app doesn't compile (as you would expect if the theme is missing) so it doesn't make sense to talk about further details. I have made my custom dark theme and it works well just it required quite a lot unnecessary work.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the information that it worked for you, I'll try on the clean new project it would be useful to know that it works like that.

Comment: @IvanIčin I have updated my answer and this should fix your issue. And yes try it out on a new dummy project and see.

Comment: I really can't agree. As you can see I am getting the information from the compiler that the theme doesn't exist. I don't have a custom style.xml in night folder, but those issues are irrelevant (and I don't think that you need a custom there style.xml as far as I have read, my own custom theme works perfectly without that).

Comment: @IvanIčin This error occurs even if you do have the library and yes it won't compile when you have it. As I've mentioned make sure you are declaring parent for your theme as Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight not android:Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight as this also causes the above error. However, if you have done what I have mentioned in the answer and still it doesn't work it's unfortunate. But at least someone will find this answer helpful.

Comment: I've made it to work on the new project, not sure what is wrong on my existing project, possibly it is a matter of some cache though it is still unclear. However as said above there is no need for values-night folder it works without that, obviously you can customize some things that way but it is not necessary to make it work and that was the wrong information.

Comment: Yes obviously values-night folder is not required to support dark theme, however it is recommended to have that as it gives ability to customize your theme and controls to better suit the dark theme. Anyway, good to know you were able to make it work. From what I can say from the given info in your question, the problem most likely could have been that you had declared parent="android:Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight" instead of parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight".